# How to reference grandparent in scss?

Tags: css, sass

I have a scss question.

Lets say I have something like this

```
.footer-logos {


  &__link {


    &:nth-child(2) a{
    }

    &:nth-child(3) a {
    }

    &:nth-child(4) a {
    }
  }

  &__imagelink {
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have &:nth-child(n) a. I want this to be like a has the class .footer-logos__imagelink. I tried to do like below

```
&:nth-child &__imagelink
```

Obviously, that did not work. I wonder how I can reference it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Goal: `.footer-logos__imagelink`

`&` gives the parent's full selector, to achieve your goal you need to concatenate it with the child, to do so we can use string interpolations!

```
.footer-logos {
  #{&}__imagelink {

  }
}
```